# Find values close to multiples in NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows:

```
array([    90.,    180.,    270.,    360.,    450.,    540.,    630.,
      720.,    810.,    900.,    990.,   1080.,   1170.,   1260.,
     1350.,   1440.,   1530.,   1620.,   1710.,   1800.,   1890.,
     1980.,   2070.,   2160.,   2250.,   2340.,   2430.,   2520.,
     2610.,   2700.,   2790.,   2880.,   2970.,   3060.,   3150.,
     3240.,   3330.,   3420.,   3510.,   3600.,   3690.,   3780.,
     3870.,   3960.,   4050.,   4140.,   4230.,   4320.,   4410.,
     4500.,   4590.,   4680.,   4770.,   4860.,   4950.,   5040.,
     5130.,   5220.,   5310.,   5400.,   5490.,   5580.,   5670.,
     5760.,   5850.,   5940.,   6030.,   6120.,   6210.,   6300.,
     6390.,   6480.,   6570.,   6660.,   6750.,   6840.,   6930.,
     7020.,   7110.,   7200.,   7290.,   7380.,   7470.,   7560.,
     7650.,   7740.,   7830.,   7920.,   8010.,   8100.,   8190.,
     8280.,   8370.,   8460.,   8550.,   8640.,   8730.,   8820.,
     8910.,   9000.,   9090.,   9180.,   9270.,   9360.,   9450.,
     9540.,   9630.,   9720.,   9810.,   9900.,   9990.,  10080.,
    10170.,  10260.,  10350.,  10440.,  10530.,  10620.,  10710.,
    10800.])
```

I am trying to match values that come the closest to 4300 or multiple of 4300. So the condition statement would return TRUE for the value of 4320 and 8640 in the array above and FALSE for all other values. How can I accomplish that?

TIA

Edit 1:

After looking at the answer, I need to clarify. I was looking for the closest value within +-20% of the multiple to return TRUE.

Comment: What is the maximum expected tolerance?

Comment: trying to match the closest value within +-20% of the multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, cf. my comment to @jakevdp's answer, only one value should be returned for each multiple. In that case, you can obtain the indices through broadcasting by doing something like

```
a = np.arange(0, np.max(x)+4300, 4300)[np.newaxis].T
b = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.bool_)
b[np.argmin(np.abs(a - x), axis=1)] = 1
```

where `x` is your input array. In the given example, this produces

```
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Edit: The updated question adds the requirement that the given result moreover be within a certain range of the multiple. We can handle that by adding an extra step to the above:

```
a = np.arange(0, np.max(x) + 4300, 4300)[np.newaxis].T
idx = np.argmin(np.abs(a - x), axis=1)
b = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.bool_)
b[idx[np.abs(x[idx] - a.ravel()) < 4300*0.2]] = 1
```

In this case, `b` becomes

```
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Edit #2 given the comments for @jakevdp's answer: To ignore the first multiple, just use

```
a = np.arange(4300, np.max(x)+4300, 4300)[np.newaxis].T
```

instead

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a bunch fuglede!

Comment: You're welcome! If you found the answer helpful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the modulo operator and the floor division operator:

```
>>> tol = 20
>>> x[x % 4300 <= abs(x // 4300) * tol]
array([ 4320.,  8640.])
```

---

Edit:

Given the updated question (finding the *closest* match within a particular tolerance), what you're looking at is a specialization of a nearest neighbors problem. I'd probably do this with scipy's cKDTree, to be most efficient. For example:

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

>>> tree = cKDTree(x[:, None])

>>> queries = 4300 * np.arange(np.floor((x / 4300).min()), np.ceil((x / 4300).max()) + 1)

>>> queries
array([     0.,   4300.,   8600.,  12900.])

>>> d, i = tree.query(queries[:, None], k=1)

>>> x[i]
array([    90.,   4320.,   8640.,  10800.])

>>> tol = 0.2

>>> x[i][d < tol * x[i]]
array([  4320.,   8640.,  10800.])
```

Comment: why do we need `abs()` here?

Comment: If I'm reading their question correctly, they want at most one result for each multiple; that is, if 4310 were part of the array, only 4310 and not 4320 would get marked.

Comment: @fuglede Ah, that wasn't clear to me. But if that's true, why is 10,800 not in the expected output, as it's closest to 3 * 4300?

Comment: @jakevdp: I was wondering the same: I would imagine the maximum element to be flagged no matter what. cndata: Can you clarify?

Comment: I was only looking for the element to match if it is within a certain range of the multiples of 4300. I realize now that the limits of the range need to be considered as well..so match the closest value within +-20% of the multiple.

Comment: @cndata: In your updated question, it says 20%; which one is it? In either case, 90 is within 10% of a multiple of 4300, so why is that not flagged?

Comment: For this problem, I wasn't looking for the zero multiple...the first match i was expecting was 4320 and so forth...so long as the value was within +- 20% of the multiple...